# How can I find user role in Mysql?

Tags: database, mysql

```sql
SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key= .$wpdb->prefix. _capabilities AND meta_value= ROLE in serialized array.
```

How can I set `meta_value` in serialized array?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: This can be done via WP CLI without needing to write out a big SQL query, and it can be done pretty easily with `WP_User_Query` in PHP

Comment: @Tom J nowell Thans for your reply! Isn't it better to use query directly rather than use WP_User_Query regarding DB performance?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference if the query comes from PHP or if it comes from an SQL client, chances are you're using PHPMyAdmin anyway. Just note that if you need to query for something that's inside a serialised PHP string, you're in for a world of pain, for which there isn't a 100% foolproof solution. The recommended solution for querying serialised PHP data directly is **don't**, there are other ways to get the data

Comment: I see @TomJNowell Thanks for your help. It helps a lot :) So is it better to store plain value instead of using serialized array and take out with SQL query? I had found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116419/mysql-select-query-within-a-serialized-array

Comment: Yes, especially where user meta is concerned, you can have more than one user meta with the same key as well. But if you really must store a structured value as a string, don't use PHP serialisation either, use JSON. There is a Q on this stack that asks how to do it, which got a lot of answers and upvotes, including one ultra sketchy way to do it that sometimes works, but it also has a lot of examples of better ways to deal with it

Comment: @TomJNowell I got it. Thank you so much. Have a good one! :)

Comment: Awesome, if you found a solution can you post it as an answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use plain Key according to @TomJNowell 's comments.
If I would like to search a key in serialized data, I would get those serialized array from DB and use maybe_unserialize() in PHP OR use WP_User_Query in PHP.
Thank you @TomJNowell